# Async function | Await not waiting for promise {Partially D.js}

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, async-await, discord.js

```
async function find(a) {await message.guild.members.resolve(a).displayName}

let Del = find("350994324072300547")
message.channel.send(Del)
```

I want **Del** to *"be"* `message.guild.members.resolve("350994324072300547").displayName` and for `find` to wait for the promise.. What am I doing wrong?

The result I get is `[object Promise`]

Comment: you have to put “await” in front of the call to the “find” function: let Del = await find

Comment: Had already tried that, says ```await is only valid in async function``` (Talking bout let Del)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `await` to the find call. And wrap the entire code in a [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) async function.

```
(async function() {
    async function find(a) {
       return await message.guild.members.resolve(a).displayName
    }

    let Del = await find("350994324072300547");

    message.channel.send(Del);
})();
```

Comment: Had already tried that, says  ```await is only valid in async function``` (Talking bout let Del)

Comment: Edited my answer for that problem. You have to wrap the code into a function which is immediately invoked / called.

Comment: It should not throw the same error. Something else is wrong. 
We wrapped the code in a function and prefixed the function with the `async` keyword. This should remove the error `await is only valid in async function`. Are you sure that you are facing the same error?

Comment: I want to send Del later as a part of a different message, I also have multiple variables with different values as Del

Comment: Thanks! I just realized a can just add my other variables, and the other messages!